# Navigation Drawer above my XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I try to put my Drawer Navigation above my layout/include_pub" and listViews.
I would like my Navigation Drawer be just below my id "header".
With this XML, nothing appear and I don't know why ?
I have a white view just below my header.
Thanks for advance for yours answers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/include_splash" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_l_tout_accueil"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/i_b_menu_accueil"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/i_v_logo_accueil"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t_w_rubrique_accueil"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/i_b_reload_accueil"
                    android:layout_width="35dip"
                    android:layout_height="35dip" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <include layout="@layout/include_pub" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/l_l_articles_accueil"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/l_v_articles_accueil"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/r_l_videos_accueil"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/l_v_videos_accueil"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/l_l_evenements_accueil"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/l_v_evenements_accueil"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/l_l_magazines_accueil"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/l_v_magazines_accueil"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dip"
                    android:background="@color/line" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/teeeeeext"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- The navigation drawer -->

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="#333"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#666"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15sp"
                android:paddingRight="15sp"
                android:paddingTop="15sp" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout needs to be the root element

Comment: I know @TomHart but : LinearLayout/ -include_splash -l_l_tout_accueil -drawer_layout With this order drawer_layout is a root element and doesn't work too. My include_pub and my ListView don't appear, I have a white view...